Как сделать так, чтобы видео открывалось только в своем мобильном приложении
Пишется мобильное приложение на React native. В приложении будут видео, которые можно будет загрузить себе на мобильное устройство. Как можно было бы сделать так, чтобы загруженное на устройство из приложения видео открывалось только в этом приложении? В какую сторону вообще смотреть, на какие библиотеки или ключевые слова? Заранее большое спасибо за ваши комментарии

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Гугли "DRM", но чую ошибку XY.

@SeVlad спасибо, переформулировала текст вопроса, надеюсь, так понятнее

Ответил, но чувство ошибки XY не оставляет.


Как можно было бы сделать так, чтобы загруженное на устройство из
приложения видео открывалось только в этом приложении?

Технология называется DRM, но это при желании обходится.
Более надёжно для данной задачи - создать свой формат/контейнер видео :)
Но и это не спасёт от записи экрана.

Спасибо, нашла в пакете "expo-video" (который скорее всего будет использоваться), что можно указать "DRMType", например "widevine"
